# Strange values for primitive array in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, malloc, primitive

I've created an Objective-C class called `IntArray` which holds a C array of `int`s and methods to access it and manipulate it.

For the most part, it seems to have been working well, but I've encountered a strange problem. I have created two instances of `IntArray` in one class and I'm now trying to access them in another class.

The first `IntArray` seems to be working fine, but the second, when I log the values, has strange values scattered around the array, such as `-536870912` and `62026224`.

These values aren't being added by the code so I can only assume it's a problem with regards to the memory address of the C array, but I can't work out the cause.

```
@implementation QPIntArray
{
    int   *_array;

    int _columns;
    int _rows;
    int _layers;

    int _count;


    float _tileWidth;
    float _tileHeight;
    float _tileDepth;

}

    - (instancetype)initArrayWithColumns:(int)c rows:(int)r tileWidth:(float)tw tileHeight:(float)th
    {
        if (self = [super init])
        {
            [self setArrayColumns:c rows:r layers:1];
            _tileWidth = tw;
            _tileHeight = th;
        }

        return self;
    }


    - (void) setArrayColumns:(int)c rows:(int)r layers:(int)l
    {
        _columns = c;
        _rows = r;
        _layers = l;

        _count = ((c * r) * l);

        free(_array);
        _array  = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * ((c * r) * l));
    }
```

I'm simply creating two instances of this class. One class called `LevelData` and then passing this class to another called `TileMap` and retrieving the `IntArray`s from `LevelData` within the `TileMap` class, the first `IntArray` seems to work fine but the second has these strange values and the code consequently doesn't work as intended.

```
//In LevelData

 _tilemap1 = [[QPIntArray alloc] initArrayWithColumns:_columns rows:_rows tileWidth:_tileWidth tileHeight:_tileHeight];

_tilemap2 = [[QPIntArray alloc] initArrayWithColumns:columns rows:rows tileWidth:cellWidth tileHeight:cellHeight];

//In TileMap
- (instancetype)initWithLevelData:(QPLevelData*)levelData
{
      if (self = [super initWithLoopDirection:QPMapLoopNone map:levelData.tilemap2])
     {}

     return self;
}
```

Comment: Where/how are you actually putting data into the array?

Comment: The first array is populated by level data which uses <NSXMLParserDelegate> the second isnt populated it has the default values of 0 Im using it as a means to mark whether an area of the map has spawned its objects 0 = not spawned 1 and above = spawned

Comment: As an experiment If I create the IntArray in the constructor of tileMap thus... if (self = [super initWithLoopDirection:QPMapLoopNone map:[[QPIntArray alloc] initArrayWithColumns:16 rows:2 tileWidth:320 tileHeight:320]]) Then it works as expected but obviously thats not what I want to do